# Linux/OSX equivalent of windows PlaySound

Tags: c#, mp3, playback

Due to the lack of a managed .NET api for playing MP3 files, I'm using the `PlaySound(byte[])`  as P/Invoke and it is now playing the MP3 file successfully.

I can't use any third party libraries due to license restrictions.

Now, I want to port the application to Linux and OS X using Mono but I'm unsure which P/Invokes should be used on those platforms.

An answer to a similar question said

> You can just open("/dev/dsp") and write to it. That's as "native syscall" as you can get, I believe.

but I don't know how to do that in C#

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the SDL_Mixer library with the SMPEG library for mp3 support. The code should be reusable across all OS's.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't use any third party libraries due to license restrictions.

Comment: libsdl is under the GPL or zlib license depending on the version which are permissive, for MP3 you're going to have to use a library. You can always convert them to a different format that's free.